# Message is not showing in Chrome and IE while it is working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox

This Div message is getting changed and being showing in Firefox, but it is not showing in chrome.

This is the HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative; color: Green" id="divMessage">
<input type="button" value="value" class="abc" id="btnClick" name="Submit" />
```

Javascript:

```
var strMessageEmpty = "";
var strMessageSavingInProgress = "Saving Data.  Please wait...";
var strMessageDone = "Module Calculation has been done...!";
$("#btnClick").click(function() {
    $("#divMessage").val(strMessageEmpty);
    $("#divMessage").html(strMessageSavingInProgress);
    // SAVE DATA
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        //  contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        //  dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            Period: $('#ddlPeriod').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#divMessage").html(strMessageSavingInProgress);
            key = data;
        },
        error: function(err) {}
        $("#divMessage").val(strMessageEmpty);
    });
```

Comment: Your included markup is missing a closing tag for the div; was this by design, or just a typo? It's technically required if you're using an HTML5 doctype: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element

Comment: Check if all the divs are rendered properly using inspect element

Comment: @Pradeep, change $("#divMessage").val(strMessageEmpty); to $("#divMessage").html(strMessageEmpty);

Answer (score 0):

I believe $("#divMessage").val(strMessageEmpty); should be placed outside the $.ajax call (or you may want to put it elsewhere but it's current placement isn't right):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    //  contentType: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    //  dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        Period: $('#ddlPeriod').val()                     

    },

    success: function (data) {     
             $("#divMessage").html(strMessageSavingInProgress);                 
                 key = data;
    }, error: function (err) {

    }
});
$("#divMessage").val(strMessageEmpty);
```

**Update**: As others pointed out, you need to properly close the div tag like so:

```
<div style="position: relative; color: Green" id="divMessage"></div>
```

Comment: Actually it is working very fine in Firefox but not showing in Chrome (Because it is fetching data quickly). Is there any way to show it up in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, but the problem I pointed out above is still a problem with your code. It's not valid Javascript. Answer Updated